# Back Button in fragment opens up and closes navigation drawer instead of going back

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer, android-drawer, android-fragmentscenario

I have a navigation drawer which is working absolutely fine with drawer icon, however, if I move from navigation drawer activity to any of my fragment, back arrow is also displayed but on clicking of back arrow navigation drawer opens, I just want to set my action on back button click instead of an opening drawer. Please help me in rectifying this issue.

My drawer activity code is below

```
toggle?.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(false);

    drawer_layout.addDrawerListener(toggle!!)
    toggle!!.syncState()


    val header = (findViewById<NavigationView>(R.id.nav_view)).getHeaderView(0)


    toggle!!.isDrawerIndicatorEnabled = false


    toggle!!.setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_profile_icon)

    usernameTv = header.findViewById(R.id.username_tv)
    profileImage = header.findViewById(R.id.profile_image_user)
    userDesigTv = header.findViewById(R.id.user_designation_tv)
    pointsTv = header.findViewById(R.id.points_tv)
    userPhotoImv = header.findViewById(R.id.profile_image)
    headerLayout = header.findViewById(R.id.header_layout_profile_edit)
    mainWidgetBottomMenuLayout = findViewById(R.id.main_widget)
    addProductTv = findViewById(R.id.add_products_tv);
    createJobTv = findViewById(R.id.create_job_tv);
    createPostTv = findViewById(R.id.create_post_tv);
    closeBtn = findViewById(R.id.close_btn);

    bottomNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.navigation)

    drawer = findViewById<DrawerLayout>(R.id.drawer_layout)

    navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view)


    toggle?.setToolbarNavigationClickListener {
        if (drawer!!.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer!!.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START)
        } else {
            drawer!!.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START)
        }

    }
    navigationView?.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this)

    loginSession =
        Session(
            this
        )
    val isloggedin = loginSession!!.isLoggedIn


    addProductTv?.setOnClickListener()
    {

    }

    createJobTv?.setOnClickListener()
    {
        val fragmentTransaction1 = supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
        fragmentTransaction1.replace(R.id.container, JobPostFragment())
            .addToBackStack(null)
        fragmentTransaction1.commit()
        closeBottomSheet()
    }

    createPostTv?.setOnClickListener()
    {

    }

    closeBtn?.setOnClickListener()
    {
        closeBottomSheet()
    }

    val fragmentTransaction1 = supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
    fragmentTransaction1.replace(R.id.container, FeedsViewFragment())
        .addToBackStack(null)
    fragmentTransaction1.commit()



    viewmodel = ViewModelProviders.of(this, factory).get(LoginViewModel::class.java)

    viewmodel?.getLoggedInUser()?.observe(this, Observer { it ->
        setData(it)
    })


    if (isloggedin && loginSession!!.loginDetails.get(Constants.USERTYPE).equals(Constants.COMPANY)) {
        populateMenuForCompanies()
    } else if (isloggedin && loginSession!!.loginDetails.get(Constants.USERTYPE).equals(
            Constants.INDIVIDUAL
        )
    ) {
        populateMenuForIndividual()
    }
```

In my fragment

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

```
    (activity as AppCompatActivity).supportActionBar!!.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)
    (activity as AppCompatActivity).supportActionBar!!.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true)

    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
}
```

Please let me know how to go back to previous fragment onclick of back arrow instead of opening navigation drawer.

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: Please post complete code/snippet for your implementation of Nav Drawer

Comment: It isn't clear for me how do you work with your fragments, but the idea is to put fragments to backstack via fragment manager and pop the stack when back button is pressed. If the stack is empty, than show your navigation drawer, otherwise pop stack.

Comment: only problem is if i click on back button in my fragment it opens drawer instead of my action

Comment: @HarshJatinder just added the code in detail